# Android Studio - Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Android Studio 2.3.2 and Gradle 3.3. i just downloaded android studio and made a project. The target of the project is Android KitKat. When I try to run it, it gives and error saying "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'..."

I just created this project and have not added any code.

Full Error Screenshot:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Try `Build > Clean Project` and then build it again

Comment: Are you using user **bill** to start the Android Studio? Try to use command **unzip** to extract the zip file to see whether it can be extracted.

Comment: Just tried Clean Project, but the same error still comes up! Also, unzip seems to have successfully unzipped the classes.jar file.

Comment: @WhatsYourIdea Can you build your project in command line? In your project root folder, execute "gradle assembleDebug"

Comment: @cmoaciopm Ubuntu asked me to install gradle with "sudo apt install gradle". And after the installation, I ran "gradle assembleDebug". And this time, another error showed up. Error: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9184u8a65l33uno/GradleVersionError.txt

Comment: @WhatsYourIdea Ubuntu release bundled gradle(2.10) is too old to compile the project. From the log, you should use gradle 3.3 to compile your project. I recommend you to use **sdkman** to install gradle. Refer http://sdkman.io/install.html.

Comment: @WhatsYourIdea Or else you can use execute "./gradlew assembleDebug" in your project root, if you don't want to install gradle by yourself. This method is much simpler.

Comment: @cmoaciopm gradlew didn't work either. It showed the same error as android studio gave me.

Comment: @WhatsYourIdea Can you take a screenshot of your command line console? Which user are you using to execute the gradle command line?

Comment: @cmoaciopm I am not using root but a normal account to execute gradle. Screenshot: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9jlsgb19d98rcim/ErrorMessage.png

Comment: @WhatsYourIdea Weird. Try "rm -rf /home/bill/.android/build-cache" to remove the build cache, then rebuild.

Comment: @cmoaciopm Thank you! I finally found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search, I finally found the cause and the solution.

## Cause:


The problem was caused by an automatically mounted ntfs hard disk. I saved all my projects files in an ntfs partition, but Ubuntu recognized the ntfs partition as a removable device (e.g. USB).

## Solution:


1. Run `sudo umount <name of the drive (e.g. /dev/sda1)>` to unmount the drive in problem.
2. Run `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup` to make a backup of fstab.
3. Open /etc/fstab with any text editor.
Here, find the line that specifies your ntfs partition.
The line should look like this:

```
UUID=<16 digit uuid>    <something>     ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46              0      0
```

Add `errors=remount-ro,uid=1000` after `defaults,umask=007,gid=46`
So after the change, it will look like this:

```
UUID=<16 digit uuid>    <something>     ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46,errors=remount-ro,uid=1000    0      0
```

4. Reboot your system

Now, gradle should not give the execution failed error anymore.